# debug python api: where to view `web.debug` messages

Tags: python, api, debugging, nginx

I inherited an NGINX server, which hosts an API, as part of a research project I'm involved in. I am responsible for the iOS portion, but I've been getting a lot of `500 Internal Server Error` which is obviously a problem for the app.

Unfortunately, the grad students who built it are long gone and there are no READMEs to help get me acquainted.
I've never worked on an API before and am struggling with figuring out how this one works/how to debug it.

I see in the code some commented out `web.debug` messages. For example:

```
def imgpath2url(path):
    """Given a path for an image (e.g., from the 'leaf' table of the database     ), returns a valid API url"""
    els = path.split('/')
    #web.debug('Getting imgurl for %s' % (path))
    if path.startswith('findingspecies'):
        return '/species/' + fixspeciesname(els[1]) + '/images/' + els[-1]
    elif path.startswith('uploads'):
        id = os.path.basename(path).rsplit('.',1)[0]
        return '/%s/original.jpg' % (id)                                     
    return ''
```

Where are these debug messages printed out to? Are they printed out to a browser? Can I view these printed debu statements as I make calls to the api within the iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

The errors in this case are usually written to the web server error logs which in case of NGINX can be found at /var/log/nginx/error.log check that file using any text editor i.e nano or use cat, tail.

Also the web debug functions seems to belong to a framework like Odoo or so (A non-native python function). Which can be isolated if you can share more code or name the specific framework the API is built on.

Comment: Hi Zeeshan - welcome to SO! What part of the code would be helpful to share to identify the specific framework?

Comment: Have you tried checking the NGINX logs file yet? 

Secondly, you can try finding the defined web.debug function via looking for matching patterns of "def debug" in your code

Comment: I am checking the NGINX log files - but I can't find these debug messages (I uncommented the one in my original post). I also don't see any def debug in my api.py file where `web.debug` is used